# Multi threaded server for each indiviual clients

Tags: java, sockets, connection, client, serversocket

Okay have a question, I have a server, this server is multi threaded in a way that it allows several clients to connect to it. When a client connects to the sever it's thrown into a thread to do its task, and so on for the other clients.

Basically what the client does is draw a 'Graphics' square to the screen, and when you move this square on the screen (with keyboard events, arrow keys) it will send the x and y cordonate to the sever to be placed into an array corresponding index to the client number given to the client in the beginning connection.

My problem isn't sending the x and y cords to the server, no matter how many clients I have connected they all work and send there x and y cords to the server to be stored, and of course when the player makes a new move, the previous x and y in the array is overwritten with the new x and y cords.

My problem is drawing each client (not include its client) to the other clients screen...

So basically if I was to move my square on my client's screen it would move on everyone's screen (thats connected to the server of course). I was thinking id have a multi threaded server for each client, meaning id have two threads per connection. But if I'm sending stuff back and forth at the same time in two threads the socket will get confused. And plus I want the client to be continually receive this array of x and y cords, not just when it moves, so that it will update everyone if someone makes a move. And also I want the server to continually be sending the x and y cord array to ever client while in additionally taking in new x and y and making the correct changes to the array.

I'll post the basic structure to what I have and if someone could point me in the right direction, do I have to make another server socket and accept another socket in the client?

So confused on how to go about having multiply threads per connection. Thank you! :)

Client Side:

```
//some methods are taken out 
// All imports imported here
public class ClientSquares extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    //variables here
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                 //other calls here (just for client)
                if(online == true && (x != oldX || y != oldY)){
                    //only sends its X and Y cords when the player makes a move.
                    checkAbility check = new checkAbility(x, y, clientNum, alpha);
                    check.checking();
                    //the Checking method in checkAbilities class just assigns a client           
                    //number to this client, which is stored in a int variable called  
                    //clientNum, once its assigned then it can send its x and Y cords
                }
                Thread.sleep(3);
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error in implemented Runnable's method Run");
       }
  }

//paint method stuff here, paints the the clients square, and everyone else (according 
//to the array received from the server.

  public static void main(String [] args){
       //thread for client started here
  }
  public ClientSquares(){
    //standard jFrame here, creates standard x and y cords here

    //This is how im making my connection with the server right now.. further 
    //communication (in getting client number, and x and y cords are done in a 
    //different class)
    try{
        sock = new Socket("localhost",4000); 
        OS = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        IS = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        OIS = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        roomNum = IS.readInt();
        players = new int[roomNum + 1][2];
        defaultPlayerArray();
        online = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.err.println("Cannot connect to the Server, check and make sure that the" + 
                         " correct ip is entered, and also check if port 777 is open" +
                         " you will now enter offline mode.");
        online = false;
    }
   }
   class AL extends KeyAdapter{
      //Key events here
   }
}
```

Server Side:

```
//import heres
public class ServerRunner{
    //variables here, and this class is called somewhere else to start the server, 
    //which 
    //has the server socket, and a couple more variables
    public ServerRunner(Server2 ser){
        serv2 = ser;
        players = new Socket[ServerRunner.roomNum + 1];
        xy = new int[roomNum + 1][2];
        gui = new GUI();
        string = new String[0];
    }
    //start method is called in the class above, which passes it a server2 object 
    //(itself)
    public void start(){
        try{
            serv2.dataServ = new ServerSocket(4000);
            serv2.listening = true;
            defaultArray();
            gui.main(string); //the GUI class just draws the players for the server to
                              //see
            System.out.println("Listening for Connections...");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("The port number 777 and 778 are not open");
        }
        while(serv2.listening){
            try{
                //the data class gives the client a client number, and stores the x & y
                //cord
                new data(serv2.dataServ.accept()).start();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error in Server Runner");
            }
        }
    }
    public void defaultArray(){
        for(int i = 0; i < xy.length; i++){
            xy[i][0] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me with this problem! :)

Edit:
In all I have one socket that im using, but i need to do multiple things with this socket (threads), how do i go about doing this without getting data mixed up, should I just make another serverSocket?

The client would send its x and y cords to the server to be stored in an array, but would also be receiving an array full of the other players x and y cords to draw on its screen at the same time... See this is where the threads come into place, but very difficult if not impossible to do with one socket

Comment: Please, put some line breaks in your text ;)

Comment: He just wants to express how confused he is also confusing us :)

Comment: @Daniel H: what messages do you think would be necessary for communication b/w the clients and the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have two threads per connection in the server. One listens to client updates; for each client update it receives it does the proper processing, and at the end it emits an event that the internal state has been changed.

The other thread listens on the the 'internal state modification' event, and when it receives one, sends the new state to the client.

Now, you will need to implement the whole event thing carefully, as you have multiple emitters, a single event, and multiple receivers.

The client will have to have two threads again, one that sends messages to the server, and one that receives the updated state; synchronizing them should be easy.

Also, don't do this...

```
IS = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
OIS = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

... because reading from IS and OIS interchangeably might lead to problems.

Comment: Im still very confused at what you said there... im confused in away on how to go about doing that.....

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to register every client at the server. Then, every client has to open its own server port. Whenever a client sends new coordinates to the server, the server has to send this new coordinates to every client other than the one which sends this coordinates.